# How can i get current workflowinstance id using java?

Tags: java, alfresco

I am using Alfresco community edition-5.1.x , I have created custom advanced workflow, In workflow have step  of auto generate document functionality using script step (java delegate), I need to save document as a `workflowintanceid` of workflow, so how can I get the `workflowintanceid` using java code?

Comment: I have difficulties to understand what you want exactly. Could you please rephrase your question, maybe add some context (code, from what you want to get the workflowinstance id, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to get the workflow instanceid on your delegate. If so, then use the below code in your delegate.

```
@Override
public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception
{
 String workflowInstanceId = ActivitiConstants.ENGINE_ID + "$" + execution.getProcessInstanceId(); 
 //.... rest of the code goes here...
 }
```

Please let me know, if I understood your question wrongly.